# Good practices for handling TLS LetsEncrypt with Kubernetes Service

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt

Considering a Nginx reverse-proxy handling TLS LetsEncrypt certificates "in front" of a backend service, what is the good deployment architecture of this setup on Kubernetes ?

My first thought was do make a container with both Nginx and my server in a container as a Stateful Set.
All those stateful sets have access to a volume mounted on `/etc/nginx/certificates`.
All those containers are running a cron and are allowed to renew those certificates.

However, I do not think it's the best approach. This type of architecture is made to be splited, not running completely independant services everwhere.

Maybe I should run an independent proxy service which handle certificates and does the redirection to the backend server deployment (`ingress` + `job` for certificate renewal) ?

If you are using a managed service (such as GCP HTTPS Load Balancer), how do you issue a publicly trusted certificate and renew your it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/blob/master/README.md).

> kube-lego automatically requests certificates for Kubernetes Ingress resources from Let's Encrypt

It works with GKE+LoadBalancer and with nginx-ingress as well. Usage is trivial; automatic certificate requests (including renewals); uses LetsEncrypt.

The README says -perhaps tongue in the cheek- that you need a non production use case. I have been using it for production and I have found it to be reliable enough.

(Full disclosure: I'm loosely associated with the authors but not paid to advertise the product)